# ROSJava .launch files and parameters

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering how to put a ROSJava node within a launch file.  I also want to pass parameters to the ROSJava program, just like in C++ and Python nodes.  I cannot find documentation on this problem (at least not a simple copy/paste solution).  There is some code [in this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12549/how-to-create-a-launch-file-with-a-node-developed-with-rosjava/)

```
<node pkg="rosjava_bootstrap" type="run.py" args="bumperCar org.lejos.ros.nodes.bumpercar.BumperCarControl" name="BumperCarControl" />
```

but this does not work for me, as I have no file named *run.py* within the *rosjava_bootstrap* package.  I installed ROSJava within the past two months, so my ROSJava version should be up-to-date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52217/rosjava-.launch-files-and-parameters/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The run.py script hasn't been used in a long time. You'll need to use the Gradle `installApp` task (see [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)) and then configure your launch file to execute the generated binary/script. This will hopefully become easier in the future.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on 2013-03-05**:
Got it, thanks!  Here is a sample launch file entry for anyone wondering: